# Ignore nulls in Spark/Scala DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to ignore nulls from spark data frame using groupBy but it didn't working

+----------+--------------+--------+------------------+--------+

|JoB       |         Code1|      Code2|       Code3|       ID|

+----------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------+

|         0|                  Haa|                   null|                     null|      85|

|         0|                   null|                    HN|                  null|      85|

|         0|                   null|                   null|                   191|      85|

|         0|                   null|                    CE|                  null|      85|

|         0|                     HRa|                   null|                  null|      85|

|         0|                   null|                   null|                   348|      85|

|         0|                   null|                   null|                   203|      85|

|         1|                     UlS|                   null|                  null|      85|

|         0|                   null|                    HV|                  null|      85|

|         1|                   null|                   null|                   840|      85|

|         1|                   null|                    UA|                  null|      85|

|         0|                     ClZ|                   null|                  null|      85|

+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------+

expected output

+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+

|JoB       |                  Code1|                  Code2|                 Code3|      ID|

+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+

|         0|                     Haa|                    HN|                   191|      85|

|         0|                     HRa|                    CE|                   348|      85|

|         1|                     UlS|                    UA|                   840|      85|

|         0|                     CIZ|                    HV|                   203|      85|

+----------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------------+--------+

Comment: Are you sure it's really a `null` and not a string "null"? I thought default behaviour groupBy is to not use `null` as a key and drop it

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
df.filter(col("column_name").isNotNull)
```

read [this article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-filter-rows-with-null-values/#:%7E:text=While%20working%20on%20Spark%20DataFrame,values%20results%20in%20unexpected%20values.) to